# Calling Model Functions from a Library

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, class

I have turned a normal PHP class into a library so I can use it in Codeigniter as a library. I can load it and call the functions I need in that class. [**Here is that class to help with the question**](http://utilitybase.com/paste/28561).

However, there are quite a few points where I have to call functions in my class. These functions reside in the model that instantiated my class. How can I do this as currently normal calls don't work. Here is my code:

---

```
class Controlpanel_model extends Model {

    var $category = '';
    var $dataa = 'a';

    function Controlpanel_model(){      

        parent::Model();

    }

    function import_browser_bookmarks(){

        $this->load->library('BookmarkParser');
        /*
        *In this function call to the class I pass 
        * what model functions exist that it should call
        * You can view how this done by clicking the link above and looking at line 383
        */
        $this->bookmarkparser->parseNetscape("./bookmarks.html", 0, 'myURL', 'myFolder'); 
        return $this->dataa;

    }

    function myURL($data, $depth, $no) { 

        $category = $this->category;
        $this->dataa .= 'Tag = '.$category.'<br />'.'URL = '.$data["url"].'<br />'.'Title = '.$data["descr"].'<br />'.'<br /><br />';
    } 

    function myFolder($data, $depth, $no) {

        $this->category = $data["name"];

    }   

}
```

Thanks all for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, you are having problems calling the model's functions passed to your bookmarkparser?

Within your Library, you'll need to reference the Model itself and it's functions via:

```
// Based on the signature you provided
parseNetscape($url, $folderID, $urlFunction, $folderFunction) {
   get_instance()->Controlpanel_model->$urlFunction();
   get_instance()->Controlpanel_model->$folderFunction();
}
```

We need to use get_instance() since Libraries don't inherit all the CI goodies.
This will assume that your model has already been loaded.  I'm not sure what you were having problems with, referencing the $CI instance or dynamically calling functions.

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Perfect - just what I was looking for!